# Could you explain the structure of the highlighted sentence,please!. The passage is from the reading section in Toefl test of Barron

Tags: expressions

Could you explain the structure of the highlighted sentence,please!. The passage is from the reading section in Toefl test of Barron.
Thanks in advance.

The status of women in a society depends in large measure on their role in the economy. the reinterpretation of the paleolithic past centers on new views of the role of women in the food-foraging economy. Amassing critical and previously overlooked evidence from Dolní Ve vstonice and the neighboring site of Pavlov, Olga Soffer, James Adovasio, and David Hyland now propose that human survival there had little to do with manly men hurling spears at big-game animals. Instead, observes Soffer, one of the world’s leading authorities on Ice Age hunters and gatherers and an archeologist at the University of Illinois in Champaign-Urbana, it depended largely on women, plants, and a technique of hunting previously invisible in the archeological evidence—net hunting. ***This is not the image we’ve always had of Upper Paleolithic macho guys out killing animals up close and personal***, Soffer explains. Net hunting is communal, and it involves the labor of children and women. And this has lots of implications.

Comment: Can you give us more details about what you don't understand? Or which bits you do understand?

Comment: Good heavens, what a terrible paragraph.  I hope the real TOEFL isn't like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is not the image 
  (that) we’ve always had 
      (the image) of Upper Paleolithic macho guys 
            (who are) out, killing animals 
                  (in a manner that is) "up close and personal"
```